# JavaScript checking an array of objects is coming up false when it should be true

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, object, if-statement

Working on a pseudo login form and ran into a problem with the if-else statement. I created a function to check an array of objects when submitted and see if they match the text inside the input. The last else statement is supposed to print only if the email input is not found. I discovered taking out the last else statement fixed the issue, but made it impossible to print 'user not found' if there were no matches. Pretty sure it's a simple fix but I cannot seem to find what is wrong.

How do I get this to run properly without deleting that last else statement? (Included the HTML for reference.)

```js
var logForm = document.querySelector("#logForm");
var output = document.querySelector("#output");

var users = [{
  email: "email1@address.com",
  password: "123"
}, {
  email: "email2@address.com",
  password: "123again"
}, {
  email: "email3@address.com",
  password: "123again2"
}];

var submitHandler = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  output.innerText = '';
  var inputEmail = logForm.email.value;
  var inputPassword = logForm.password.value;
  console.log(inputEmail);
  console.log(inputPassword);
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if (inputEmail === users[i].email) {
      if (inputPassword === users[i].password) {
        output.innerHTML = "Successfully logged in as " + users[i].email;
      } else {
        output.innerHTML = "Invaild password.";
      }
    } else {
      output.innerHTML = "User not found.";
    }
  }
};


logForm.addEventListener('submit', submitHandler);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Login Form</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    <form id="logForm">
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail"></input>
      <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password"></input>
      <button type="submit">Log In</button>
    </form>
  </p>
  <p id="output"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Whoa whoa whoa, why are user login details being stored client-side?

Comment: It's not a real login. Just practice for object searching in the array.

Answer (score 3):

You need to stop search once user is found in the array. To do so you need to `break` the loop or simply return from the function:

```
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if (inputEmail === users[i].email) {
        if (inputPassword === users[i].password) {
            output.innerHTML = "Successfully logged in as " + users[i].email;
        } else {
            output.innerHTML = "Invaild password.";
        }
        break;
    } else {
        output.innerHTML = "User not found.";
    }
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5mfaoz9e/1/

Comment: shouldn't the break be directly after `code`output.innerHTML = "Successfully logged in as " + users[i].email; and  @ShadowMorphyn although this would work it would be very unsafe anyone could just read the javascript and find the username and password... this is better handled by php

Comment: @Zenonline We should break in both cases `Successfully logged in as` and `Invaild password.` because in both cases uses is actually found so we need to stop searching.

Comment: @Zenonline And regarding security. Yes, of course you are right, it's not secure to store passwords in JS code, but I guess OP is just learning and working on some basic app.

Comment: ahh missed that bit with the correct email you are absolutely right my brain overlooked that completely

Comment: This worked. Thank you! @dfsq you are right this is not a real login. Just practicing searching objects in an array via input.

Answer (score 1):

Three things to fix your problem:

1. Declare a boolean variable let's say `userFound` and set it to true if the email input is found inside the `for` loop.
2. Use `break` statement at the end of `if (inputEmail === users[i].email)` block to stop the `for` loop once the email input is found.
3. Move `output.innerHTML = "User not found."` outside of the `for` loop and only execute that statement if `userFound` equals false.

Below is the modified code

```
var userFound = false;

for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if (inputEmail === users[i].email) {
        if (inputPassword === users[i].password) {
            output.innerHTML = "Successfully logged in as " + users[i].email;
        } else {
            output.innerHTML = "Invalid password.";
        }
        userFound = true;
        break; // stop the iteration
    }
}

if (!userFound) {
    output.innerHTML = "User not found."; // only do this if user isn't found
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rjdxxvmk/